# How to catch the "@" character input from keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml

I was trying to use the event `keyDown` event in a wpf textbox control and capture clicked keys with `e.Key`, however since the at "@" character doesn't have a key, I can't catch it. How do I detect the "@" key clicked

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.) // nothing corresponding the at key 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyDown` is for actual keys, it does not concern itself with their interpretation. Use [`PreviewTextInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx) instead for example.

```
private void RichTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Text == "@")
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Keydown event uses keyboard buttons. It does not really know anything about characters.

Try using the KeyPress event instead. Instead this event returns the ASCII char code of the key just pressed.

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '@') MessageBox.Show("The At sign was pressed");
}
```

Note: Characters that are not ASCII will not trigger this event.

Comment: This be WPF, there is no such event.

Comment: this is wpf, this event doesn't exist